# Unable to receive response inspite of giving right API key in node js post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

Please help me with the below POST request that I'm trying to make. Below is the code snippet.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
//const request = require("request");
const https = require("https"); 
const request = require('request-promise');
const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/test.html");
});

const data = {
  "some_header":{
      "name":"xxxxx"
    }
};

const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(jsonData);
app.post("/post", function(req, res){
  const url = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
    json: true,
    headers: {
     ContentType: "application/json",
      Authorization: "nhgjgjhgjghjghj"
  }
  }


  const request = https.request(url, options, function(response) {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      // res.send("success");
      console.log("success");
    } else {
      //res.send("Failed");
      console.log("failure");
    }
    response.on("data", function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    })
  })

  request.write(jsonData);
  request.end();
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
  console.log("The app is up and running on Port 3000");
});
```

I'm getting 200OK response from the external server, but unable to post the data. When I logged the response data from the server, I received this `success
{ require_login: true }`

"Success" is the console log message. require_login: true is the response I'm getting from the server. where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you going to use basic authorization and send base64?

Comment: yes  just the basic Auth

Answer (score 1):

Try to add **Basic** before you api key. Also, if you are using base64, then check that original string is right one and should be something like: login:password

```
headers: {
     ContentType: "application/json",
      Authorization: "Basic BAsE64Format or api:key or login:password"
  }
```

Comment: headers: {
     "Content-type": "application/json",
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from('CtB2HZwaRdGggr1g4K').toString('base64')
  }

Comment: enclosing the content-type with quotes and converting the API key to base 64 did the trick. Thanks for the support. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
headers: { "Content-type": "application/json", Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from('CtB2HZwaRdGggr1g4K').toString('base64') }
```

enclosing the content-type with quotes and converting the API key to base 64 did the trick